# Map function and View object (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, view

I read somewhere that the map function in Python returns a "view" object - I think that's a typo - Could someone please shed light on this.

My understanding is that a view object is a special class of iterables - if so,what features qualify an iterable to be a view object.

Comment: No, `map` returns an iterator. A "view" is anything that wraps the underlying data of some object inside another, distinct object. Not directly related. You may be thinking of `dict.keys` and `dict.values` and `dict.items` which return *views* over the data in the dictionary, to provide objects that do something specialized without having to copy underlying data. A view need not be an iterable, although, they usually are, since you take a view over some container, and you often want to be able to iterate over whatever view. But it isn't inherent to the concept of a view.

Comment: Thank you so much - this is most helpful!